# ¿Cuál sería el equivalente en MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

¡Hola!

Suelo trabajar con MySQL pero recién me pasaron un codigo en SQL Server que no logro comprender.
Me podrían ayudar explicándome cual es la función en el codigo de las siguientes sentencias: `default user_id()`y `as user_name()`.

¿Y cuál sería su equivalente en MySQL?

```
create table cliente (
id_clie int not null primary key (id_clie),
nom_clie varchar (40),
rfc_clie varchar(11) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT check_rfc CHECK (rfc_clie LIKE
                     '[A-z][A-z][A-z][A-z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'),
tel_clie varchar (15) constraint df_tel_cte default '999999999999999',
dir_clie varchar(40),
suspendido bit default 0,
user_id int default user_id(),
nomb_usuario as user_name());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***user_id int default user_id ()*** establece una valor por defecto para las inserciones en esa tabla. Correspondiente con el número de identificación para un usuario de la base de datos.

[image: Resultado]

De manera que se así gestionan los usuarios que realizan la conexión, mediante esa columna. Si no le pasas un usuario a la función, te devuelve el usuario Actual.

[User_id](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/user-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

***nomb_usuario as user_name();***

Establece una columna calculada que devuelve el nombre de usuario que ejecuta la consulta oportuna.

[User_name](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/user-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
create table cliente (
id_clie int not null primary key (id_clie),
user_id int default user_id(),
nomb_usuario as user_name());
go
insert into cliente (id_clie)
values (1)
go
select * from cliente
go
execute as user= 'TestUser'
go
select * from cliente
```

[image: Resultado]

El dato es calculado en función de quién la llame. Cada vez que se realiza una select, se vuelve a calcular.

A priori no parece que sea o fuere el objetivo, pero al no persistir el dato, este se recalcula. Lo suyo sería, supongo utilizar en la misma [persisted.](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: ¡Gracias por la explicación me sirvió mucho!